# Display element in array based on condition

Tags: arrays, bash

I have an array created and I want to look for a keyword and then if found, display the element that is n elements behind it.  Is that possible to do with bash and if so, could someone provide an example?
Example of operation:

```
element 1=red
element 2=blue
element 3=green
```

Parse through the array and if you see "green", display the element that is 2 behind it.  In this case, it would return "red".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/bin/sh

val="blue"
offset=2 #offset index when echoing
array=("red" "green" "blue" "purple" "blue")

for i in $(seq $offset $[${#array[*]}-1])
do
    if [ "${array[$i]}" == "$val" ]
    then
    echo "${array[$[$i-$offset]]}"
    fi
done
```

All simple artihmetics can be done inside `$[...]`; don't forget the `$` before the name of the variable. It is very useful when dealing with arrays in bash. note the offset at the beginning of the for-loop, avoiding useless tests of negative indexes.

Comment: Can you explain the offset?  Does that mean +2 from the value needed?  Can you also use negative numbers?

Comment: The offset is the number of elements between the current element and the display one (as in your example). For negative offset, it could work with a modification in the seq instruction: `$(seq 0 $[${#array[*]}-1-$offset])`. No modification is needed elsewhere. In order to make it working with positive and negative values, I suggest you to compute before the for loop the bounds of the seq instruction, depending on the sign of the offset, and start your for loop with `for i in $(seq $begin $end)`

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

val="blue"
array=("red" "green" "blue")

for (( i = 0; i < ${#array[@]}; i++ )); do
  if [[ $val == ${array[i]} ]] && (( i - 2 >= 0  )); then
   echo "${array[i - 2]}"
  fi
done
```

Outputs:

```
red
```

As @jordanm points out in the comments, you will need to worry about what might happen if an array index hasn't been set.

Comment: Inside of an array's `[]` (I don't recall the proper term), is already numerical context. `"${array[i + 2]}"` will work. I upvoted because this is a good enough example to get the OP started, but there are other things to worry about such as arrays being sparse and what to do if `i + 2` or `i - 2` expands to null.

Comment: @jordanm: "subscript"? And I agree, it should be `i - 2` based on the OP's use of the word "behind". Also, negative subscripts will cause an error in Bash versions before 4.2.